# What should we do with the construction of a classifier (e.g., NN) if we have more number of input features?

Tags: neural-network, dimensionality-reduction

For example, I consider an NN with n number of input units. What should the construction of NN be changed if the number of input units increases to 10*n?
I think the number of hidden units and hidden layer should be increased. And, we should have a higher number of samples in the dataset (e.g., using data augmentation).

I also think dimensionality reduction could be used (like word embedding).

What do you think about this problem?